# Open an image using as little RAM as possible

Tags: delphi, graphics

I want to open some relative big files (jpg, gif, bmp) using as little RAM as possible.
Inside my program I need all open files converted to BMP so I can process them. However the conversion from JPG to BMP takes 27.1MB of RAM if I use the classic conversion code:

```
function ConvertJPG2BMP(FullFileName: string; BMP: TBitmap);
VAR JPG:  TJpegImage;
begin
 JPG:= TJpegImage.Create;
 TRY
   TRY
     JPG.LoadFromFile(FullFileName);
     BMP.Assign(JPG);
   EXCEPT
   END;
 FINALLY
   FreeAndNil(JPG);
 end;
end;
```

because it uses two images (a jpeg that is transferred to a bitmap then).

--

However, if I use a TPicture to load the file, I use only 7.1MB of RAM. But in this case the TPicture.Bitmap is empty and I need a valid TBitmap object.

Is there any way to load images from disk while keeping the mem footprint small?

--

(Test file: 1.JPG  2.74MB   3264x1840 pix)

Comment: Why you need to keep mem usage low? Modern PC has usually so much memory that 30 MB is barely noticeable. If you really want to keep memory usage low, you need probably deconstruct JPEG file "block by block"..

Comment: agree with Harriv on decoding remark, tiny footprint requires a) decoding JPEG 8×8px blocks separately and b) writing raster data to memory mapped DIB section. TJpegImage and TBitmap are incapable to comply with a) and b) respectively. GPL?

Comment: Disargee about "just buy more RAM", tho.

Comment: For the sake of comparison, convert your JPEG file to BMP and load the BMP file directly. How much memory does your program consume when you skip the JPEG?

Comment: @Downvoter: I'm not suggesting buying more RAM, i'm asking what's the real problem?

Comment: @Altar: out of curiosity, why the small RAM requirement?  Are you using very old hardware, or very restricted hardware?  Your Pascal coding style (capitalised keywords) makes me curious, it's not seen very often these days :)

Comment: The jpeg file converted with irfan to bmp is 17.1MB. But I don't know it it uses some kind of RLE encoding or not.

Comment: @Harriv, i guess its a natural programmer's desire to minimize **unneeded** memory usage. And the OP's task not required having entire raster in memory. Also, OP's **test** raster is pretty small, naïve approach will eat more. @Altar, got an idea for comparison - TJPEGImage.Scale affects decoding memory footprint, make sure competing method(s) are not optimizing decompression this way.

Comment: @Downvorer - Wow, nicely said. +1 for your comment. The test image is indeed small as you said. Think about BIG images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back of the envelope calculation gives 6 mega pixels. Assuming 32 bit colour this takes you to 24MB.

You aren't going to do any better than your current code.

Comment: Hi David. I almost agree with your calculus: I think the bitmap pixels are stored on 3 bytes (no transparency). This will result in 17.1MB.

Comment: for alignment reasons even 24 bit colour consumes 32 bits per pixel

Comment: Also, how TPicture manages to load that jpeg file in only 7.1 MB?

Comment: I don't know anything about jpeg.

Comment: I'd guess 4 bytes even on disk for ease of loading and saving. Windows bitmaps are optimised for speed rather than size.

Comment: That's incorrect, 24bpp RGB triplets are... that is, triplets, DWORD alignment only occurs inbetween scanlines.

Comment: Not unless it became DDB and device is configured to 32bpp.

Comment: @Altar TPicture draws the JPEG directly using `StretchDIBits`, without any temporary TBitmap, AFAIK.

Comment: The jpeg file converted with irfan to bmp is 17.1MB. But I don't know it it uses some kind of RLE encoding or not.

Answer (score 1):

The memory usage does not come from the JPEG library, but in the way you use it.

If you convert a JPEG into a TBitmap, it will create a bitmap resource, then uncompress the JPEG into the bitmap memory buffer.

You can paint directly from the JPEG content into the screen. Depending on the JPEG implementation, it will use (or not) a temporary `TBitmap`.

You are not tied to the JPEG unit supplied by Borland.

For instance, you may try calling directly the `StretchDIBits()` windows API from the uncompressed memory buffer, as such (this code is extracted from our [SSE JPEG decoder](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/18/Fast-JPEG-decoder-using-SSE/SSE2-version-1.1)):

```
procedure TJpegDecode.DrawTo(Canvas: TCanvas; X, Y: integer);
var BMI: TBitmapInfo;
begin
  if @self=nil then
    exit;
  ToBMI(BMI);
  StretchDIBits(Canvas.Handle,X,Y,width,height,0,0,width,height,pRGB,
   BMI,DIB_RGB_COLORS,SrcCopy);
end;
```

Creating a huge bitmap is sometimes not possible (at least under Windows XP), because it uses shared GDI resources, whereas using plain RAM and `StretchDIBits` will always work, even for huge content. You can create a memory mapped file to handle the binary content, but just allocating the memory at once would suffice (and Windows will use hard drive only if short of RAM). With today's PCs, you should have enough RAM available even for big pictures. (17 MB is not a big deal, even for your 3264x1840 pix).

Then, from this global uncompressed memory buffer containing raw pixel triplets, you can use 
 a smaller bitmap corresponding to a region of the picture, then work on the region using `StretchDIBits(aBitmap.Handle,...`. It will use less GDI resource.

You could also rely for instance on GDI+ drawing, which will draw it without any temporary bitmap. See e.g. this [OpenSource unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/20/GIF,-TIF,-PNG-and-JPG-pictures-TGraphic-read/write-via-GDI). From our testing, it's very fast and can be used without any `TBitmap`. You could also ask only for a region of the whole picture, and draw it using GDI+ on your bitmap canvas: this will use less RAM. And your exe will be a bit smaller than the default JPEG unit. And you'll be able to display *and save* not only JPEG, but GIF and TIFF formats.

If you want to minimize even further the memory usage, you'll have to call directly the JPEG library, at lowest-level. It's able to uncompress only *a region* of the JPEG. So you would be able to minimize used RAM. You may [try using the IJL library](http://bouchez.info/myjpeg.html) with Delphi, a bit old, but still working.

Comment: What about the part of the question where OP says I need all
open files converted to BMP so I can
process them.

Comment: @David 1. You can process the binary content without using a global TBitmap, but using `StretchDIBits` over a smaller `TBitmap.Handle`, mapping only a region of the whole picture. 2. If you are able to work directly with regions of the JPEG (my last paragraph), you'll use less RAM and smaller bitmaps.

Comment: I'm sure you can do this if you wished. I will not be down voting your answer on the grounds that it does not address the question that OP asked.

Comment: Hi Bouchez. I have tried the SSE Jpeg decoder before but it doesn't work with all jpeg files.

Comment: "You can paint directly from the JPEG content into the screen" - The image is never painted on screen. I apply quite some processing on it then I save it as BMP. I think that if I apply the processing on small pieces some of them will not work very well as they use the neighboring pixels to calculate stuff. Probably some odd lines will appear where the big image was cut in small pieces.

Comment: @Altar The SSE is just some experiment. It won't support progressive JPEG, AFAIK.

Comment: @Altar So, you'll need to have the whole picture as bitmap. Could you work on low-level binary scanlines (RGB triplets) instead of a bitmap? What kind of process are you applying to the picture? There are some low-level features of the jpeg library able to retrieve the picture at 1/4 or 1/8 of its original size: if you are doing some resizing, it may help you. But if you work on the whole picture size, you won't have any other possibility than using a bitmap or dealing with low-level binary layout of the uncompressed JPEG.

Comment: @Altar I wrote "You can paint directly from the JPEG content into the screen" but I also explained later that "you can use a smaller bitmap corresponding to a region of the picture, then work on the region using StretchDIBits(aBitmap.Handle,...". That is, painting the JPEG into the small bitmap, just as if you paint it on screen.